# Pushforward of invariant measures (equivariant Moser theorem)

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, equivariant, noncompact

There is a well-known theorem that between any two absolutely continuous Borel probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is an increasing triangular
transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\nu = T_∗\mu$ (see, for example, “[Triangular
transformations of measures](https://doi.org/10.1070/SM2005v196n03ABEH000882)” by Bogachev, Kolesnikov, and Medvedev).

There is another version of this theorem for smooth manifolds (non-compact Moser theorem).
If  $M$  is a  noncompact connected oriented manifold and  if $\mu$ and  $\nu$ are  volume forms on  M  with $\int_M \mu = \int_M \nu \le \infty$   and  if  each end  of  the manifold $M$  has finite $\mu$  volume if it has finite $\nu$  volume and  infinite $\mu$ volume if it  has  infinite $\nu$  volume, then there is  a  diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$,  such that  $\phi^* \mu = \nu$. (See "[Diffeomorphisms and volume-preserving embeddings for noncompact manifolds](https://doi.org/10.2307/1998183)" by Greene and Shiohama.)

I am curious about the equivariant analog of either of these results.

More precisely, assume that a (compact?) group $G$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two $G$-invariant (smooth) densities. Does there always exist a $G$-equivariant diffeomorphism $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\nu = T_∗\mu$?

Could you point out if this result is proved somewhere in the literature? Does the group $G$ have to be compact for it to hold?

Comment: I added links to the papers, but there are two papers called "Triangular transformations of measures" by the same authors.  I can't read Russian, so am not sure how they're related.  I hope the link I gave was to the right one.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about the way in which $G$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I don't have a specific assumption on the action and I am more or less okay with any non-restrictive assumptions. However, the action should not be free. As an application in mind, I have a Euclidean group acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$.